# How do I dynamically name a model of a directive scope with 2 way binding?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm trying to use a `ng-repeat` to dynamically pass in an object value to a directive, like so:

```
<td ng-repeat="attr in demographicAttrs">
  <yes-no name="{{ attr }}-{{ $index }}"
    model="ambassador.demographic.{{ attr }}"
    update="calcScore(ambassador)"></yes-no>
</td>
```

where the directive is defined as

```
function (
  $rootScope
) {
  "use strict";

  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'templates/yesNo.html',
    scope: {
      "name": "@",
      "model": "=",
      "update": "&"
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('model', function(value) {
        scope.update();
      });
    }
  };
};
```

So I'm trying to dynamically generate the model to be watched in `ambassador.demographic.{{ attr }}`, but the `=` 2 way binding for directives, doesn't like the value being generated that way.

I get this error: https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=is%20an%20unexpected%20token&p2=24&p3=ambassador.demographic.%7B%7B%20attr%20%7D%7D&p4=%7B%7B%20attr%20%7D%7D

How would I do this?

### Updates

- I've also tried doing it with `ambassador.demographic[{{ attr }}]`, but that doesn't work either (close, but need to remove {{ }}, as per https://stackoverflow.com/a/23405825/111884)
- I found this [Setting dynamic scope variables in AngularJs - scope.<some_string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875486/setting-dynamic-scope-variables-in-angularjs-scope-some-string), but `$parse` doesn't seem to work in html

Comment: what about changing it conceptually and move the repeat inside the directive (and just passing the whole model object)? would that work for your use case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the model expression to use the javascript bracket notation:

```
model='ambassador.demographic[attr]'
```

<kbd>[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/GruffBunny/J35D3/)</kbd>

Comment: That works! But mine looked more like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Zgm5X/2/ (which errors when you click on the radio buttons). Needed to also initialise the `demographic` key, as per: http://jsfiddle.net/Zgm5X/3/