# Does AngularJS have a function like eval?

Tags: angularjs, eval

Does AngularJS have any function or method similar to `eval`?

I need to get the value of a previously-defined variable, e.g.:

```
data.mess_5 = "Hello"
c = 5
x = eval( "data.mess_" + c )
```

Comment: Massive sad face. eval kills unicorns. `x = data["mess_"+c];`

Comment: Also, if you spelled the name correctly you might find it easier to search for information about **AngularJS**.

Comment: I mean, angularjs is still javascript, so.... you can use eval if you really want to.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angularjs is javascript, so you can use eval, assuming your var is on the global scope. However, in this particular case (*and most other cases*), eval is the wrong tool for the job.

```
data.mess_5 = "Hello"
c = 5
x = data['mess_' + c]
```

Answer (score 1):

Check the $parse function (taken from [Setting dynamic scope variables in AngularJs - scope.<some_string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875486/setting-dynamic-scope-variables-in-angularjs-scope-some-string))

```
var the_string = 'life.meaning';

// Get the model
var model = $parse(the_string);

// Assigns a value to it
model.assign($scope, 42);

// Apply it to the scope
$scope.$apply();
console.log($scope.life.meaning);  // logs 42
```