# Create dynamic scope variables in AngularJs inside loop

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am new to Angular.js and am trying to create dynamic scope variables in AngularJs inside a for Loop. This is something as below:

```
$scope.lists=[{listName:'list1'},{listName:'list2'}];

for(var i=0;i<$scope.lists.length;i++){
  var listName = $scope.lists[i].listName;
  listName = $parse(listName);
  listName.assign($scope,[]);
  $scope.$apply();
}
```

The above code throws an error saying: `$digest` already in progress.

The code works ok when used without looping just for one as done in:
[Setting dynamic scope variables in AngularJs - scope.<some_string>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875486/setting-dynamic-scope-variables-in-angularjs-scope-some-string)

I ultimately am looking for `$scope.list1=[]` and `$scope.list2=[]` as 2 separate arrays.

Any leads would be awesome. Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

> The above code throws an error saying: $digest already in progress.

You're already in the controller and in angular scope. So no need to trigger the digest loop using `$scope.$apply()`. Even if you have to must check the `$$phase` and then apply.

```
if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply()
```

But for your scenario, it's not required at all

```
$scope.lists = [{listName: 'list1'}, {listName: 'list2'}];

angular.forEach($scope.lists, function(item) {
    var listName = item.listName;
    $scope[listName] = [];
});
```

Comment: how should I access those arrays in views?

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `$parse` and `assign` here, just use [bracket notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors#Bracket_notation) to access object property (because `$scope` is nothing but just an object) with variable name:

```
$scope.lists = [{listName: 'list1'}, {listName: 'list2'}];

for (var i = 0; i < $scope.lists.length; i++) {
    var listName = $scope.lists[i].listName;
    $scope[listName] = [];
}
```

Comment: I don't think that's what he's looking for because he seems to be going for the methodology defined in this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875486/setting-dynamic-scope-variables-in-angularjs-scope-some-string

Comment: Actually i am using it with angular dragdrop and by doing what u r saying throws an error saying TypeError: Cannot set property 'jqyoui_pos' of undefined ultimately meaning the $scope.list is undefined.

Comment: @AR7 This looks like exactly what he is looking for. The result here will be $scope.list1=[] and $scope.list2=[] as 2 separate arrays. The linked approach would be for implementations where the dot notation is taken into consideration.

Comment: @Vaibhav Not sure how you are using it after, but above code will create `$scope.list1 = []`, `$scope.list2 = []` properly without any problem. If you have problems that means it's something else outside of this question.