# Questions on ngshow and scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have two question on angularJS, i use differents sections and i want to show just one so i did : `<section ng-show="section6_us"> </section>` and `<section ng-show="section7_us"> </section>` for exemple and i have a lot of variable in my scope.

Can we do the thing like this ? `<section ng-show="{section6_us == "section6"}"> </section>` and `<section ng-show="{section7_us == "section7"}"> </section>`
With a variable and a compare ? it would be great because i can't use ng-switch and ng-if and i have a lots of variable like section1,section2,...section 14 etc.

Second, it's possible that we can use the scope like this ? `$scope.("section"+i) = true` for example ?

Thank you in advance
Ben

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not fully sure what you are trying to say here but as per my understanding:

It should be differnt quotes.

Note that I have used single to denote value

```
<section ng-show="{section7_us == 'section7'}"> </section>
```

Plus to store dynamic properties , you can use square brackets:
like:

```
$scope["section"+i] = true;
```

This is no angular, just plain javascript objects property addition.

Comment: Thank you it was that `$scope["section"+i] = true;` :)

Answer (score 0):

Yes to `ng-show="{section7_us == "section7"}">`

and i think you'll want to look at $parse for dynamic scope variables.

```
var the_string = 'life.meaning';

// Get the model
var model = $parse(the_string);

// Assigns a value to it
model.assign($scope, 42);

// Apply it to the scope
$scope.$apply();
```

Original link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875486/setting-dynamic-scope-variables-in-angularjs-scope-some-string)