# Get dynamic scope variable value angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I have array of object which contains number of scope variable name in it. All the scope variable value has already been set before.
Something like this :

```
$scope.myarray = [{'id':'myname1'},{'id':'myname2'}];
$scope.myname1 = 'John';
$scope.myname2 = 'Rick';
```

Now if I want to get value of the scope variable which within the 'id' of 'myarray',what should I do?
I have already tried this

```
var getMeMyValue = $scope[myarray[0]];
```

Something like this,but it didnt help.

I have seen in [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875486/setting-dynamic-scope-variables-in-angularjs-scope-some-string) that how to set scope variable dynamically
But I didnt get anything about how to get value dynamically
Please help me with this,Thanks!!

P.S. Here I'm dynamically getting my scope variable so there is no way that I can access them directly to get their value

Comment: it work `$scope.myarray = ['myname1','myname2']; var getMeMyValue = $scope[myarray[0]];`

Comment: can you show working sample how you try, and what error you have?

Comment: Or can you please create an sample in http://jsfiddle.net?

Comment: Thanks @grundyGrundy, for consideration. Actually i have scope variable that assigned to several html component (textbox,combobox,etc) as per they created dynamically and I set the id same as the scope variable. I also stored these variables in a array above shown manner.

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle or plunker? now not quite clear where is problem in your code

Comment: @sam, also i'm sure you not need save id for textbox, combobox and other html component, can you provide sampl problem what you try solve?

Comment: i guess @brocco 's answer going to solve my problem.First i was using 'id' to get my value using jquery but after started to use angular,this problem arised. But i guess it solved now. Thanks grundy for your help and consideration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will get the value for you dynamically:

```
var getMyValue = $scope[$scope.myarray[0].id];
```

Comment: I think this will solve my problem. Thanks @brocco and sorry that i cant gives you thumbs up..not enough reputation :P

Comment: No problem, if this does solve your problem, please mark it as the accepted answer (even if you cannot upvote due to rep)

Answer (score 0):

Please check this http://plnkr.co/edit/ZwwuKRVwgD74ufY2GmB8?p=preview

Controller -

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', [ ]);

app.controller('myController', function($scope) {
  $scope.myarray = [{'id':'myname1'},{'id':'myname2'}];
  $scope.myname1 = "John;"
  var getMeMyValue = $scope[$scope.myarray[0].id];
  console.log(getMeMyValue);

});
```

Comment: your answer same as @Brocco answer

Comment: Ohh yes.. I have not checked.