# Get dynamic scope array variable value in angularjs

Tags: arrays, angularjs, angularjs-scope, dynamic-scope

I have a scope array variable which i am trying to access dynamically. Its value has been already set.

Its like this.

```
$scope.setp = { arr: [] };
$scope.setp.arr[0] = "sample Value";
```

When I am trying to access it dynamically as below I get undefined.

```
console.log($scope['setp.arr[0]']);
```

However I am able to access it directly using the following.

```
console.log($scope.setp.arr[0]);
```

The way of dynamically getting value of scope variable works fine for others but fails when the variable name contains square brackets i.e. [ ].

I followed this [example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30457851/get-dynamic-scope-variable-value-angularjs) but no success for scope variable containing array or square brackets [ ].

Also dynamically setting of scope array variable using $parse service works fine as in below.

```
var scopeVariable = $parse('setp.arr[0]');
scopeVariable.assign($scope, "new Value");
```

Comment: `$scope['setp'].arr[0]` or `$scope['setp']['arr'][0]` if you want to go real cray cray.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This won't work `console.log($scope['setp.arr[0]']);` as its trying to access a property `setp.arr[0]`. You can access it like `console.log($scope['setp']['arr'][0]);`