# Angular - Dynamically Build A Scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ngmodel

Is it possible to achieve something along the lines of this

```
var count = 1;

var blah = $scope.someThing_ + count;
```

So that blah would be equal to

```
$scope.someThing_1
```

I feel like this should work, but it does not seem to be working!

Thanks :)

Comment: $scope.someThing_ is not a string, count is not a string. Why should it work? And more importantly, what are you exactly trying to achieve?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting dynamic scope variables in AngularJs - scope.<some\_string>](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875486/setting-dynamic-scope-variables-in-angularjs-scope-some-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure that it is good idea to store data with dynamically created names of variables, but if you really need in it you could work with properties in js also in this way:

```
$scope["property_name"]
```

It means that you could save some value with counter like that:

$scope["someThing_" + count] = "value"