# how can create dynamic variable in angularjs view

Tags: angularjs, variables, dynamic

I want to do something like this in angular how can you do this?

```
$scope.test = "foo"; 
$scope.foo = "bar";
```

and in view

```
<span>{{scope[test]}}</span> <!-- and return $scope.foo that is "bar" -->
```

Comment: see this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875486/setting-dynamic-scope-variables-in-angularjs-scope-some-string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be with bracket notation:

```
<span>{{this[test]}}</span>
```

`this` points to current scope object, so with variable `test` beeing "foo", the expression will reference `$scope.foo`.