# Angular js - Append value to scope variable

Tags: jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am building app where I want to dynamically create one array which I have to assign to dynamically created table using ng-repeat.
In my directive I have appended tr like :

```
 link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
    $(elem).click(function () {
             var tmpl="<tr ng-repeat='orders in allCurrentTakeAwayOrder'>
                       </tr>";
    });
  }
```

and this is repeating multiple time on button click event.
I want to append a dynamic id to this `<tr>` as

```
 <tr ng-repeat='orders in allCurrentTakeAwayOrder"+scope.divId+"'>
```

and it is appending successfully.
But problem is that how can I append same id to that variable in controller, when assigning a data to that variable?

```
app.controller('orderController', function ($scope){ 

  $scope.allCurrentTakeAwayOrder **<i want to append that id here>**  ="data will be here to be display in table"

});
```

Comment: I refer you to a previous post which can assist with what you are trying to achieve: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18875486/setting-dynamic-scope-variables-in-angularjs-scope-some-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To append `scope.divId` to scope variable name, use a function with a property accessor:

```
<!-- replace with function
   <tr ng-repeat='orders in allCurrentTakeAwayOrder"+scope.divId+"'>
-->

<tr ng-repeat='orders in computedList()'>
```

JS

```
scope.computedList = function() {
    return scope["allCurrentTakeAwayOrder"+scope.divId];
};
```